# Rollback ROS Version

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Recently I stopped being able to compile a package, both on ros Jade and Kinetic and my answer is if I can revert the ROS version to one in which my package worked. I don't know if I made myself clear but that's basically it!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259663/rollback-ros-version/) by [sirsomething](https://answers.ros.org/users/28660/sirsomething/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install an older version of ROS (I assume you want ROS Indigo) alongside Jade and Kinetic. Which version of ROS is active and used depends on which setup.bash file you source in your terminal. Most people have one sourced automatically in `.bashrc`, but some people do not so they can choose which version of ROS to use manually.

So to change to an older version, you need to install the version you want to use, and you need to change the line in your shell init script to source that version (or remove the line and type it manually when you want to use ROS). You should also probably clean your workspace's build and devel directories, too.

If the older version you want to use is not available for your OS version, you might need to install it from source (see http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source).

You are also free to remove your current versions of ROS and install an older one instead.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sirsomething](https://answers.ros.org/users/28660/sirsomething/) on 2017-04-19**:
That's not what I want. I just want a previous Jade version, not a previous distro

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-19**:
You will probably need to install from source, and it will be hard to identify the specific versions of packages you need. If you know which package is causing problems you can check out an earlier version of just that package's source into your workspace. Catkin will use it over the system version.

**Comment by [sirsomething](https://answers.ros.org/users/28660/sirsomething/) on 2017-04-20**:
Hum. At least that's a start. Can you point me to where can i download previous ros/ rospackages versions?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-20**:
If you go to the package's wiki page, there will be a link to the source. If the source is in a repository, you need to find the tag corresponding to the version you want and clone that into your workspace. If you provide what package is causing the problem and the error, we can help more.